# New build - No BIOS screen, no POST beeps

Tags: boot, cpu, motherboard, bios, post

So trying to build a new AMD based system, but having no such luck - the power LED and CPU fan turns on, but no POST beeps or BIOS screen. Specs and list of things I've tried below. Any suggestions?

Specifications (all parts are brand new unless noted otherwise):

- CPU: AMD Ryzen 3 1200
- MB: Gigabyte GA-A320M-S2H
- CPU Cooling: Stock AMD fan
- PSU: Corsair CX-430M (used from another system)
- Generic system speaker

With this combination I get the power LED and CPU fan turning on, but nothing else...no beeps, nada

What I've tried:

- Different motherboard (Asrock B450M Pro 4)
- Different CPU (AMD Athlon 3000G)
- Different PSU (Corsair CS-550M, used from another system)
- Different system speak (speaker works ok in another PC)
- Removing CMOS battery for ~30 mins and then reinstalling
- Resetting CMOS jumper
- Confirmed that both ATX 24 and 8 pin power connectors are correctly installed
- [This diagnostic list](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/perform-these-steps-before-posting-about-post-boot-no-video-problems.1285536/)

So, I've tried different combinations of MB, CPU, PSU, CMOS, system speaker and nothing:( The only thing I haven't changed is the system builder i.e. me

Any suggestions on what I'm missing?

Edit: I'm trying to boot this up with only those components listed above, nothing else i.e. the bare minimum, no RAM, no GPU etc.

Comment: Is your motherboard ready for the Ryzen 3 1200? It may need a bios update. Unless the different CPU AMD Athlon 3000G didn't work either. Also, is there onboard VGA and dedicated VGA? If so, have you tried both? Sometimes the onboard is used during boot before it is changed in the bios.

Comment: But yeah, this can literally be anything. All hardware can be defective. You need to narrow it down by reducing the system to the bare minimum and test those components to find the problem. That includes memory

Comment: You haven't changed the RAM yet...? Try only one stick at a time?

Comment: When I had a similar problem about 4 months ago it was a defective motherboard.

Comment: Just to confirm where are you plugging in the Graphics output cable? Both Ryzen 1200 & GA-A320M-S2H do not have any onboard graphics. With this system you need a discrete graphics card. The VGA/HDMI ports on the board are applicable only when you install a compatible CPU that has built-in graphics. It seems you have not mentioned what graphics card are you using. Yet you have tried with 3000G which is APU and you still did not get any output. So may be the problem could be elsewhere. So you will have to try all further troubleshooting with 3000G CPU. Continued..

Comment: Also how many RAM sticks you have? Try with just one and try it in each and every slot. It has been my observation that most modern AM4 boards do not have Speaker enabled by default in the UEFI. So unless you actually access UEFI and set it to enabled, Speaker may not beep. This is how it's at least on my MSI AM4 boards.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved: @patkim hit on what was happening. Both MB's are brand new out of the box. I was being conservative in building them up, so starting with the bare minimum (PSU, MB, CPU, HSF, speaker only - no RAM, GPU etc.) to make sure the basics were all good. However, the onboard graphics (in this case the Athlon 3000G) requires RAM to produce a video signal and the UEFI has boot up beeps disabled by default, then it looked like some combination of PSU/MB/CPU was defective. I put in a single stick of RAM, and now everything is back in action!

Comment: Just in case you have bought only 1 stick of RAM and that's what you plan to use, then for best optimization of the system, the motherboard manual generally specifies which is the slot where you should install it (as long as it's a single RAM stick). Preferably use the single stick in that slot for best optimization. It does not mean that system won't work if you choose to install it in any other slot though.